# Proving that if a sequence converges weakly, then their set of norms is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis, weak-convergence

We are given that if $\{\Lambda_n\}\subset X^*$ (where $X^*$ is the dual space of some Banach space $X$) converges weakly to some $\Lambda\in X^*$. That is $\Lambda_n x\to\Lambda x$ as $n\to\infty$.How would we go about showing that $\{\|\Lambda_n\|\}$ must be bounded?

Comment: [Uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle), a.k.a. Banach–Steinhaus?

Comment: aka Principle of Uniform Boundedness (PUB)